# GCC: Print the value of a symbol during the link process?

Tags: gcc, arm, ld, cortex-m

Is it possible to have LD print the value of a symbol as it goes along? May be there is a silly way to just print the value?

Here are details related to my issue for context:

I am compiling code for a Cortex-M7 using GCC 4.9. The processor has two banks of flash. 1MB each at `0x0020.0000` and `0x0800.0000`.

In the CRT code it attempts a PC relative load of the address of `main` to `R2` and then branch to it. The value stored in the constant table is incorrect however.

From debugger disassembly:

```
ldr r2, =APP_ENTRY_POINT
    4A29        ldr r2, 0x002003B8
--- thumb_crt0.s -- 226 ------------------------------------
blx r2
    4790        blx r2
```

objdump of thumb_crt0.o:

```
000000aa <start>:
  aa:   2000        movs    r0, #0
  ac:   2100        movs    r1, #0
  ae:   4a29        ldr r2, [pc, #164]  ; (154 <memory_set+0x8a>)
  b0:   4790        blx r2
```

Word stored at offset:

```
ldr r2, =APP_ENTRY_POINT
    080007ED    .word 0x080007ED
```

Actual main address according to `nm`:

```
Silverback: nm Nucleo.elf | grep main
002007ec N main
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found a nice option to `ld` to print mapfile to stdout, just grep what you want afterwards:

```
g++ a.cpp -Wl,-M | grep -w main
```

yields (windows):

```
0x00000000004015dc                main
```

note: when you `objdump` an unlinked object file, relocations/call addresses are often wrong: the linker has not been run yet.

Comment: Thanks. I am having a map file created. I understand that the object file has not yet been located. What was useful for me is that it highlighted PC relative load and that led me to see the incorrect value stored at the offset. In the object file you can see that it wants to replace that location with main.

Comment: There is also the `ASSERT` directives and math operation which you could check a variable instead of printing it.  However, a mapfile is always useful.